# Java not listening for socket messages

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple problem here(I think?) but could not find the solution after searching around. Below is my client code, the problem with this code is that after I send a username to the server, it doesnt receive any message back from the server ( while the server does send one), I can't really follow the flow of my application with the while loop, can anyone explain to me where im going wrong with this?

Happy   flow:
C:  connect
S:  HELO    welcomemessage
C:  HELO    username
S:  +OK username

BROADCAST MESSAGE
C:  BCST    message
S:  +OK

```
public class Main {

BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
String Serveraddress = "localhost";
int Serverport = 1337;
String username;

private void run() throws IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket(Serveraddress, Serverport);
    System.out.println("Connected: " + s);

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    Scanner cmd = new Scanner(System.in);// console scanner
    String line = "";
    String cmdLine= "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Server: " + line);
        if (line.startsWith("HELO")) { //hij moet eerst naam invoeren
            System.out.println("\nVoer een username in");
            username = cmd.nextLine();
            out.println("HELO " + username);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(username + " is verstuurd naar de server");
        }
        if (line.startsWith("BCST")) {
            System.out.println("Bericht binnen van de server: \n" + line);
        }
        if (line.startsWith("-ERR")) {
            System.out.println(" Error gekregen van de server " + line);
        }
    }
    while((cmdLine = cmd.nextLine()) != null){
        out.println("BCST " + cmdLine);
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Main client = new Main();
    try {
        client.run();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Server probably not running :" + ioe.getMessage()); // if server not running
    }
}
```

}

My problem is this code

```
while((cmdLine = cmd.nextLine()) != null){
        out.println("BCST " + cmdLine);
    }
```

Where should this piece of code be, because after I enter a username, it doesnt check if I typed in something in the console.

Console log :
Connected: Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=1337,localport=52469] Server: HELO Welkom to WhatsUpp!
 Voer een username in username
 myUsername  < sent to server
is verstuurd naar de server 
Server: +OK username  (ack from server)
Message to be broadcasted (then i type this to be sent to server)

Message to be broadcasted is supposed to sent to the server, however it does nothing, so it doesnt enter the while loop of cmdLine 
Any tips/advice much appreciated

Comment: You should try to debug your program. What most likely happens is it gets stuck waiting for another message from server after you've read the first one. But it's not exactly clear from your question alone, you should also attach your existing log to the question.

Comment: Connected: Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=1337,localport=52469]
Server: HELO Welkom to WhatsUpp!

Voer een username in
username
username is verstuurd naar de server
Server: +OK username
Message to be broadcasted


Message to be broadcasted is supposed to sent to the server, however it does nothing, so it doesnt enter the while loop of cmdLine

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question body, comments are bad place to post this kind of information.

Comment: My bad, just updated the question body.

Comment: You can check to see if anything is `available()` to read before doing the reading.

Answer (score 1):

`readLine` is blocking and never returns `null`, so you have infinite loop where you reading data for sending while yo actually never read what you get back.
my suggestion will be to have read and write on separate threads or use non blocking io.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and watch the messages that Client and Server sends. Your in.readline() is expecting a \n at the end of the server message. If \n is missing, readline() will hang forever. If you are not in control of the server code, consider reading the bytes received and logging them to avoid using Wireshark all the time.

Comment: Is there a command that is better then in.readline(), that doesnt need expect a \n? I think this is the issue since it indeed hangs. I will install wireshark as soon as im home to check this out

Comment: @RohminMirza user902383 suggested to use read() and write() on separate threads. That makes the client a bit more complicated. You can search the nets for socket client examples, I remember there are enough.